# create category detail list map that shows detail of category in flutter dart

Tags: flutter

I have created a demo for better understanding map list

here I have some data that contains transactions and I want to make a getter that shows category based details like,

number of entries of particular category, totalexpense of particular category,

I have tried my way but feeling like child coding, so want to know any other short code

here are my data

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> transactions = [
  {
    'category': 'Food',
    'amount': 100,
  },
  {
    'category': 'Travel',
    'amount': 30,
  },
  {
    'category': 'Food',
    'amount': 90,
  },
  {
    'category': 'Travel',
    'amount': 50,
  },
  {
    'category': 'Shopping',
    'amount': 1300,
  },
  {
    'category': 'Food',
    'amount': 130,
  },
];
```

and I want output map list like each map as following

```
[{
'category':'Food','total':1200,'entries':2

},
{
'category':'Travel','total':120,'entries':4

}
]
```

here is my getter for available categories

```
List<String> get availablecategories {
  List<String> categories = [];

  transactions.forEach((element) {
    if (!categories.contains(element['category']))
      categories.add(element['category']);
  });
  return categories;
}

List<Map<String, dynamic>> get categorydetails {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> templist = [];

  print(totalexpense);
  availablecategories.forEach((element) {
    var temp = transactions.where((trans) {
      return element == trans['category'];
    }).toList();

    int totalexp = temp.fold(0,
        (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element['amount'] as int);

    templist.add({
      'category': element,
      'amount': totalexp,
      'entries': temp.length,
    });
  });
  return templist;
}

void main() {
  print(categorydetails);
}
```

Comment: I did not understand your question?

Comment: I have data of transactions...and now I want to create a list of map , and map has 3 keys :category, amount,entries. suppose I have 20 transactions of category 'food' than category detail will contain a map {'category':'Food', amount:20000,entries:20} and so on for other available categories...I have created getter named category detail and working well, but I think my code is like child code...want to improve with good one